# When I am running the demo program in flutter, it is working on Android emulator. However, it is showing error for ios emulator as below:

Tags: ios, flutter

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                           10.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
Writing result bundle at path:
/var/folders/7h/ndtlsfr17l5bq1b28cq8hsjc0000gn/T/flutter_tools.mraRyP/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirQqypht/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Failed to package /Users/Mattsmac/AndroidStudioProjects/Sample_1/flutter_application_1.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Building targets in dependency order
warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
warning: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
Result bundle written to path:
/var/folders/7h/ndtlsfr17l5bq1b28cq8hsjc0000gn/T/flutter_tools.mraRyP/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirQqypht/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
Exited

What is the fix. Android simulator it works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a dependency issue, I am not sure if it will help you, but you can try:

- Delete the Pods folder and "podfile.lock"
- Run "flutter pub upgrade" and "flutter pub get"
- then from the ios directory run these commands

  - pod repo update
  - pod install

I hope it will resolve the issue